# MDX Filter by Members

Tags: ssas, mdx, dimensions, olap-cube, ssas-2008

This is more of a general MDX question.  I want to filter those dates from the reporting date.fiscal hierarcy.  I was previously using a calculated member but I just put it in the query, it doesnt return any results.

```
    SELECT 
               { 
                FILTER (
                         [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].MEMBERS
                        ,[Reporting Date].[Fiscal].currentmember > [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-06]
                         AND
                         [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].currentmember < [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-11]
                       )

               }   on 1
              , 
               {
                  Measures.Gross
               } on 0
    FROM [Revenue]
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter the rows to a specific date range, or to dates that satisfy a filter on the values of the measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression is actually evaluating 2 tuples and then perform the comparison on the evaluated value:

> [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].currentmember > [Reporting
>   Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-06]

is :

> ( [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].currentmember ) > ( [Reporting
>   Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-06] )

where the () represent a tuple (i.e., reference to a cell in the cube). So you're comparing the cell value and not the member dates. I guess what you want is someting like:

> select   ...   {[Reporting Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-06] :
>   [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-11] }  on 1

Comment: So I really cant use the function like that all.  Where Im trying to filter members based on some other membeer value from that same dimension?  Is there any function I can do that with?

Comment: Yes you can filter; e.g., based on their 'name' starting with 'A' :  Instr( [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].currentMember.Name, 'A' ) = 1

Comment: Oh ok so it woudl be like some instr where the date is 2013 and then 03 and then 06 and 07 and 08 and 09 and 10 and 11 or something like that.  but there could be no range type filter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MDX range operator `:` to specify a literal member range

```
SELECT 
    { Measures.Gross } ON 0,
    {[Reporting Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-06] : [Reporting Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[2013-03-11] } ON 1
FROM [Revenue]
```

See documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx

Comment: This was pretty helpful. Thanks!